# Cannot install mysql-devel on centos

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, yum, rpm

Everytime I try to run `sudo yum install mysql-devel`

I am met with the following error:

```
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql-devel.i686 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql = 5.1.73-3.el6_5 for package: mysql-devel-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-devel-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686 (updates)
           Requires: mysql = 5.1.73-3.el6_5
           Installed: mysql-5.5.28-1.el6.i686 (@CentALT)
               mysql = 5.5.28-1.el6
           Available: mysql-5.1.71-1.el6.i686 (base)
               mysql = 5.1.71-1.el6
           Available: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686 (updates)
               mysql = 5.1.73-3.el6_5
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have tried running the two suggested commands to no avail.  Does anyone know what is preventing this from installing?  Do I have to set a certain package or something?

Comment: You've installed `mysql 5.5` from some weird repository (@CentALT), and the stock `mysql-devel` isn't going to help as a result, being only 5.1.  Could you **edit into your question** the output of `yum repolist`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.. assuming the `CentALT` repo doesn't `mysql-devel` `rpm`, you'd need to re-install `mysql-server`, by un-installing the one that you already have and installing it from `base` before installing `mysql-devel` (both has to be installed from same place).

```
yum remove mysql
yum install mysql-devel
```

Comment: Hmm trying to remove gives me: No Match for argument: mysql-server
.Package(s) mysql-server available, but not installed.

Comment: I updated my question with correct syntax.

Comment: after running the remove command it appears to succeed - ' Removed:
  mysql.i686 0:5.5.28-1.el6'.  However running the next command I get the exact same error as the original.

Comment: try `yum install mysql-devel` only.

Comment: I had to remove mysqlclient and mysql-libs then the install completed successfully.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql version differs from the mysql-devel version you're trying to install. This is because you have installed mysql from CentALT repo according to your output.

Try

```
yum --enablerepo=CentALT install mysql-devel
```

Comment: I get 'Error getting repository data for CentALT, repository not found' when trying to run this.

Comment: it seems you have removed the repo from your repolist. If you don't need a MysQL 5.5, the easiest thing would be to reinstall mysql from the CentOS base repo (see alexus answer).